# External class to run code on another page

Tags: c#, class, uwp

I want to create a reference for button click event which happens on another page in UWP project.

Page one (witch button):

```
private void Button_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    // some code to reference to class
}
```

Class (in external file)

```
public static void DoSomething()
{
   // Do something on Page 2 or run void on page 2
}
```

Comment: By "external file", do you mean an external DLL (a third party), or a different file under your control?

Comment: I mean a file in the same project, sorry for that

Comment: It's not a clear question. If you want to change something on the page out of page code you have to pass the page reference to other class or method and you have to make the method or element "public".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the method is `static`, you can call it without an instance of the class. Suppose the method is defined in class `OtherPage`. You could then just do:

```
private void Button_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    OtherPage.DoSomething();
}
```

In case the method is not `static`, you cannot easily do that, because there is only one `Page` instance in memory at a given time, when you have just one navigation `Frame`. It would make sense to put the method into a service class that would have a singleton instance and you could call it from anywhere. You can use MVVM framework like MvvmLight  or MvvmCross to make this easier. These frameworks also maintain navigation stack of pages and their view models so you can potentially access view model instances in the navigation backstack.